# Using kamon Akka HTTP Instrumentation only

Tags: scala, akka-http, kamon

I want to use the kamon-akka-http, currently my project have the Kamon bundle dependency which contains the kamon akka http.
The issue is that I received many other metrics from all the other instrumentation in the bundle(Akka Instrumentation, Akka Remote Instrumentation, Executor Service Instrumentation, Logback Instrumentation and Scala Future Instrumentation)

I want to receive only the akka http metrics.
I tried to remove the bundle dependency and add only the kamon-akka-http, this required that I will run the instrumation agent (Kanela).
I did that but still I saw other Instrumentation.

How can I run only Akka HTTP Instrumentation?

Answer (score 1):

I mange to disable all Instrumentation by the below configuration

```
kanela.modules {
  akka {
    within = ""
  }
  akka-remote {
    within = ""
  }
  executor-service {
    within = ""
  }
  executor-service-capture-on-submit {
    within = ""
  }
  scala-future {
    within = ""
  }
  logback {
    within = ""
  }
}

kamon.modules {
  host-metrics {
    enabled = no
  }

  process-metrics {
    enabled = no
  }

  jvm-metrics {
    enabled = no
  }
}
```

Comment: For the first part replace `kamon` with `kanela` in newer Kamon versions.